# Why do all my scenes load at startup? (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I start my game (regardless of a platform) I notice that all the scenes load in background directly after showing the splash screen. I know they're being loaded because once I try to load them from the menu they show up immediately. And it takes a lot of time to load right after startup.

However I only want to load the menu scene (title) first. And only after an option is selected I want to load the other ones.

In menu code I load scenes like this once a button is clicked.

```c#
StartCoroutine (LoadALevel ());
```

The coroutine method:

```c#
private IEnumerator LoadALevel() 
{
    async = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("space");
    yield return async;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When asking about code issues please provide a [Complete, Minimal & Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Comment: And are you sure it takes long the first time because of loading scenes or maybe it simply takes some time in general?

Comment: It's possible that loading unity is actually what's taking a while when it first starts, and that loading the levels themselves really doesn't take as long as you think it should. Have you added some logging statements so you can see exactly when `LoadALevel` is being called? That way you'll know for sure they're being called up front instead of when you click the button:
`Debug.Log("Loading scene: space");`

Comment: Thank you @derHugo and @inejwstine! You were right, it just takes a lot of time in general, I tried to build the game without two other scenes and it takes just as much time. I thought I tried this before. Sorry for wasting your time. Now I have to figure out why it takes so much time .. :D